# How to use the Qvector<QPushButton>

Tags: qt

`QVector<QPushButton*> buttonList;` global variable
`void SeatReservImpl::selectSeat(){` select seat from the gui which are pushbutton

`QPushButton* clickedButton= (QPushButton*)(sender());` select the clicked button
`buttonList.insert(clickedButton);` add to the list but gives the error:no matching function for call to QVector::insert(QPushButton*&)

`}`

`void SeatReservImpl::buyTicket(){` buy selected seats when pressed buy button
`for ( pb=buttonList.first(); pb != 0; pb=buttonList.next() )
    {
        pb->setPalette(QPalette(QColor(255,0,0)));` change the color of the buttons
    }
The problem is; the code is wrong and do not know how to fix them and the thing I want to do is how can I add the clicked pushbuttons to a QVector or Qlist and how to use the list or vector  and reach the saved button inside the list

### Edit:

Here is my code so far:

```
#include "SeatReservImpl.h"
#include <qmessagebox.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SeatReserv.h>
#include <qcheckbox.h>
#include <qpushbutton.h>
#include <qbuttongroup.h>
#include <qbutton.h>
#include <qobject.h>
#include <qwidget.h>
#include <qcolor.h>
#include <qpalette.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <qlist.h>
#include <qvector.h>
using namespace std;

QString slcSeat[10];
int i;
QList<QPushButton*> buttonList;

void SeatReservImpl::selectSeat()
{

QString slcSeat[10];

QPushButton* clickedButton = (QPushButton*)(sender());
QString buttName=clickedButton->name();
buttonList.append(clickedButton);
slcSeat[i]=buttName;
i++;
clickedButton->setPalette(QPalette(QColor(174,0,255)));

}

void SeatReservImpl::buyTicket(){

FILE *pfile;
char status[2];
int m;
int flag=0;
QString buttName,buttName1;
for(m=0;m<i;m++){
    buttName=slcSeat[m];
    system("wget -O status.txt http://embsys.heliohost.org/find.php?Seat="+buttName);
    pfile=fopen("status.txt","r+");       
    fgets(status,sizeof status,pfile);
    if(strcmp(status,"0")!=0)
        flag=1;
    }
if(flag){
    QMessageBox::information( this, "", "You Have the Seats", QMessageBox::Ok );
    QListIterator<QPushButton*> iter(buttonList);
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        QPushButton *pb = iter.next();
        pb->setPalette(QPalette(QColor(255,0,0)));
            system("wget http://embsys.heliohost.org/buy.php?Seat="+buttName);
        }
}else{
    QMessageBox::information( this, "","\t\t SORRY!!!\n One of The Seats Has Been Already Sold",    QMessageBox::Ok );
    }

    i=0;

}
```

But I'm getting compiler errors:

And the errors are;

```
SeatReservImpl.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void SeatReservImpl::selectSeat()’:
SeatReservImpl.cpp:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘QList::append(QPushButton*&)’ ../qtopia-2.2.0-FriendlyARM/qt2/include/qlist.h:61: note: candidates are: void QList::append(const type*) [with type = QPushButton*]
SeatReservImpl.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void SeatReservImpl::buyTicket()’:
SeatReservImpl.cpp:58: error: ‘class QListIterator’ has no member named ‘hasNext’
SeatReservImpl.cpp:59: error: ‘class QListIterator’ has no member named ‘next’
```

Comment: see updated answer. if that's still not good, please edit **your question** and post the exact version of Qt you are using, and the version of your compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
QList<QPushButton*> buttonList;


// add an item:
buttonList.append(clickedButton);

// iterate over all items
QListIterator<QPushButton*> iter(buttonList);
while (iter.hasNext()) {
  QPushButton *pb = iter.next();
  ...
}
```

There are lots of other ways, and `QList` is not necessarily the most appropriate container class. Please read the [Container Classes](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/containers.html) reference documentation for information about all the different options you have.

#### Edit:

If you're using a *very old* version of Qt for some reason, the `QList` class (and the iterator) don't work like that. They are a bit strange. I don't have anything to test compile this, so YYMV. Looking at the docs for [`QList in Qt 2.3`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/2.3/qlist.html):

```
QList<QPushButton> buttonList; // note: not QPushButton*

// add an item:
buttonList.append(clickedButton); // same as above

// iterate over all items
QListIterator<QPushButton> iter(buttonList);  // note: not QPushButton*
for ( ; iter.current(); ++iter ) {
  QPushButton *pb = iter.current();
  ...
}
```

Comment: I disturbed you so much but it gives errors  no matching function for call to `QList<QPushButton*>::append(QPushButton*&)` error: `class QListIterator<QPushButton*>` has no member named `hasNext` and `next` I think there are errors becouse of the versions   I am SORRY Again

Comment: I wrote all my code and all the errors. Thank you for all your help and interest.

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to the answer above, it is recommended to do:

```
QPushButton* clickedButton= dynamic_cast<QPushButton*>(sender());
```

and check whether the cast was sucessful instead of just:

```
QPushButton* clickedButton= (QPushButton*)(sender());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "SeatReservImpl.h"
#include <qmessagebox.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SeatReserv.h>
#include <qcheckbox.h>
#include <qpushbutton.h>
#include <qbuttongroup.h>
#include <qbutton.h>
#include <qobject.h>
#include <qwidget.h>
#include <qcolor.h>
#include <qpalette.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <qlist.h>
#include <qvector.h>
using namespace std;

QString slcSeat[10];
int i;
QList<QPushButton*> buttonList;

void SeatReservImpl::selectSeat()
{

QString slcSeat[10];

QPushButton* clickedButton = (QPushButton*)(sender());
QString buttName=clickedButton->name();
buttonList.append(clickedButton);
slcSeat[i]=buttName;
i++;
clickedButton->setPalette(QPalette(QColor(174,0,255)));

}

void SeatReservImpl::buyTicket(){

FILE *pfile;
char status[2];
int m;
int flag=0;
QString buttName,buttName1;
for(m=0;m<i;m++){
    buttName=slcSeat[m];
    system("wget -O status.txt http://embsys.heliohost.org/find.php?Seat="+buttName);
    pfile=fopen("status.txt","r+");       
    fgets(status,sizeof status,pfile);
    if(strcmp(status,"0")!=0)
        flag=1;
    }
if(flag){
    QMessageBox::information( this, "", "You Have the Seats", QMessageBox::Ok );
    QListIterator<QPushButton*> iter(buttonList);
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        QPushButton *pb = iter.next();
        pb->setPalette(QPalette(QColor(255,0,0)));
            system("wget http://embsys.heliohost.org/buy.php?Seat="+buttName);
        }
}else{
    QMessageBox::information( this, "","\t\t SORRY!!!\n One of The Seats Has Been Already Sold",    QMessageBox::Ok );
    }

    i=0;

}

> Blockquote
```

And the errors are;

SeatReservImpl.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void SeatReservImpl::selectSeat()’:
SeatReservImpl.cpp:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘QList::append(QPushButton*&)’
../qtopia-2.2.0-FriendlyARM/qt2/include/qlist.h:61: note: candidates are: void QList::append(const type*) [with type = QPushButton*]
SeatReservImpl.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void SeatReservImpl::buyTicket()’:
SeatReservImpl.cpp:58: error: ‘class QListIterator’ has no member named ‘hasNext’
SeatReservImpl.cpp:59: error: ‘class QListIterator’ has no member named ‘next’