# How to use the QVector with multiple object

Tags: c++, qt, qlist, qvector

I'm trying to use the `QVector` class from `Qt` to work (for me :P). What I want to do is to put multiple instances of the object `Question` in a `QVector`.

I went on multiple forums, but they're all too complicated for me as I am a beginner.
This [one post was perfect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765388/how-to-use-the-qvectorqpushbutton) but I did not find a way to resolve my problem.

So I'm turning to you to help me!

Here's the function that I want to work :

The part that create the bundle/ the vector

```
/**
 * @brief MenuQuestionnary::assembleQuiz
 * Assemble the bundle of question that will be used in Quiz class
 */
void MenuQuestionnary::assembleQuiz(){
    QVector<Question> vectorQuiz;
    vectorQuiz.reserve(spinBoxNumberOfQuestion->value());
    for(int i = 0; i <= spinBoxNumberOfQuestion->value(); i++){
        vectorQuiz.append(Question((qrand()% maximumNumberOfQuestionAvailable)));
    }
}
```

Here's my Question constructor :

```
Question::Question(int id)
{
    this->questionId = id;

    //TODO: Actually get it from DB
    this->questionText = "2+2?";
    this->explanation = "Addition mechanics";
    this->creatorId = 1;

}
```

What i expect to do here is to put the selected number of the `Question` object in a `vector`. After that i can pass it to another class. From there i should be able to extract the text from them(`questionText` and `questionExplanation`).

Comment: You can't radically change your question half-way through. Otherwise you invalidate all the answers that referred to the original instance of the question.

Comment: Should i start a new thread instead? All i changed was the int to Question after the declaration of my qvector

Comment: What's the problem now?

Comment: Append does'nt seems to exist in the vector since i declared it was a vector of question. One of my friend told me to use a QList. I'll try when i'll be home. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Can you post the whole code (in the question) with the part where you use the `QVector` and the expected results?

Comment: You should post an answer instead of editing your question to add the solution.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm not really used on all the rules here... :S

Comment: You'll be able to accept it after a couple of days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by trying few things
Here's the explanation of what i did

I've split my function in two. The first one put the element in a `QList` and the second one shuffles it.

```
/**
 * @brief MenuQuestionnary::assembleQuiz
 * @param list
 * Asseble a quiz in the Qlist and then ask shuffle to shuffle it...
 */
void MenuQuestionnary::assembleQuiz(QList<Question> &list){
    for(int i = 0; i < spinBoxNumberOfQuestion->value(); ++i){
        int rand = qrand() * maximumNumberOfQuestionAvailable;
        Question newQuestion(rand);
        list.append(newQuestion);
    }
    shuffleQuiz(list);
}

/**
 * Method Shuffle
 * equivalent to shuffling a deck of cards: we take a random one, move it to be the last one,
 * then do it again enough times to have statistically touched every card.
 */
void MenuQuestionnary::shuffleQuiz(QList<Question> &list){
    int iters = list.size() * list.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < iters; ++i){
        int rand = qrand() * list.size();
        list.append(list[rand]);
        list.removeAt(rand);
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to push objects of class type `Question` into a `QVector<int>`, which obviously is expecting an `int` instead. You should change it to `QVector<Question>` to begin with.

What I highly suggest, though, is that you read [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on C++ before going any further, or your experience with it will just get more and more complicated.

Copy pasting code from forums on the internet is **not** programming and will get you in troubles soon.

Comment: I saw the error i did when posting here. I edited my question by replacing the int by the object name. Plus i do not copy paste code, i tryed what that cageman proposed to me, played with it a bit, but I wasen't able to solve it.

Comment: +1 for "Copy pasting code from forums on the internet is not programming" :P

Comment: That's why i'm asking for an explanation. Otherwise i try what people suggest me and try to find the explanation by myself. I have read few books on c++, i have a specific problem and i need help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this: QVector vectorQuiz; vectorQuiz.reserve(spinBoxNumberOfQuestion->value()); // reserve correct amount of space in vector for performance (not required). I don't know exactly how you are going to use vectorQuiz, but maybe you should use pointers to the questions i.e. QVector and insert questions using new Question()

```
/**
 * @brief MenuQuestionnary::assembleQuiz
 * Assemble the bundle of question that will be used in Quiz class
 */
void MenuQuestionnary::assembleQuiz(){
    int iVectorSize = spinBoxNumberOfQuestion->value();
    QVector<Question> vectorQuiz;
    vectorQuiz.reserve(iVectorSize ); 

    for(int i = 0; i <= iVectorSize ; ++i){
        vectorQuiz.append(Question(i));
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code gave me this error : no matching function to call 'Question::Question()' and the error is located in the qvector.h...

Plus it says that the qVector does'nt have a function named append... Look like it's doomed :P

Comment: Seems you didn't define a constructor for Question.. i assume it is a class?

Comment: The class question is defined. Normally it is working but not when i try to put it in a vector...

Answer (score 0):

Your object (vectorQuiz) declared as vector of integers. If you want to add some integer value to it you should write something:

```
vectorQuiz.append( someIntegerValue );
```

or

```
vectorQuiz.push_back( someIntegerValue );
```

For vector of another type (i.e. Question), write code like this:

```
QVector<Question> vectorQuiz;
// ...
for(int i = 0; i <= spinBoxNumberOfQuestion->value(); ++i){
    vectorQuiz.append(Question(i)); // without [i] after vector object
}
```

And possible your should use strict inequality **<** instead of **<=** in for-cycle (but I'm not sure).

Comment: I want to put object of Question in it. I'll edit my question then.